# Google People API - listDirectoryPeople pageToken always invalid

Tags: c#, encoding, google-api, urlencode, google-people-api

The pageToken I receive on the first call, always causes HTTP 400 on my second call.

Message

> Page token is invalid. Retry call without the page token.

Status

> INVALID_ARGUMENT

When using the exact same pageToken in the "Try this API" of the documentation, it works.
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/listDirectoryPeople?hl=zh-tw

Why does it fail?

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.  as well as let us know what programming language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The pageToken parameter must be URL-encoded, for C# this would be:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nextPageToken)
```

If you want to test with Postman, use an online version, like the "Try it yourself" of the w3school article on the matter:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP